# IdentityFactoryOptions - Cannot resolve symbol Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am struggling to replicate the ASP.NET Identity samples for the 2.0.x beta packages as I cannot create a typed UserManager. The code-

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store) : base(store)
        {

        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(options.Context as ApplicationIdentityDbContext));
```

Will not compile as the IdentityFactoryOptions class does not appear to contain a symbol "Context".

When I inspect the class in Object Browser though, it contains the following properties-

```
public Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext Context { set; get; }
    Member of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions<T>

public Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { set; get; }
    Member of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions<T>

public Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IIdentityFactoryProvider<T> Provider { set; get; }
    Member of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions<T>
```

I **can** see and use the "DataProtectionProvider" and "Provider" properties. Given all three have identical access modifiers, what is preventing me from seeing and using the "Context" property, and what do I need to do to get the ASP.NET Identity samples working with the current package beta releases?

Package versions-

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.0-beta1-140211" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0-beta1-140211" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.0-beta1-140211" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: For reference I have both deleted the "bin" directory in the projects and restarted Visual Studio and the computer. Clean/rebuild solution also make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Identity 2.0.0-beta1 which was released to Nuget, please follow the best practice of using UserManager class as explained in the article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx). This should solve the errors.